# Как кешировать файлы в golang?

Tags: golang

Я хочу закешировать определённые файлы при загрузке, чтобы при запросе быстро их отдавать.

Придумал «костыльный» код, чтобы при загрузке создавались переменные и заполнялись значениями из соответственных файлов, а потом пользователю при обращении выдавалась соответственная переменная.

Как вариант, думаю создать цикл, который брал бы название переменной и путь к файлу из, например, файла (либо внутри сгенерированного файла прописать). И в цикле будет создаваться переменная и заполняться значением из файла. Или это вариант не очень?

Есть ли уже что-то готовое, что б кешировать файлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [go-cache](https://patrickmn.com/projects/go-cache/) - микро-библиотека для кэширования данных в памяти (можно указывать время жизни закэшированного объекта).

И в природе есть ещё такая штука как memcached - кэширующий сервер. Пример использования в go: https://michaelheap.com/golang-using-memcached/

Comment: У меня ещё вопрос возник. А можно ли в  go-cache выбрать группу параметров? Например param1=1;param2=2;param3=1 Вот я хотел бы получить все параметры со значением 1 ,т.е. параметр1 и 3